# Remove characters before inserting key value pairs into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file which I'm parsing to read the contents into a dictionary. However, the code below is giving me brackets surrounding every value for all key: value pairs:

```
import csv

f = open(input('Which csv file: '))
cdata = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
cdict = {}
for row in cdata:     
    cdict[row[0]] = row[1:]
print(cdict)
f.close()
```

I have tried:

```
for row in cdata:
    row = "".join(row)
    cdict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

But receive the error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

The reason I read the contents of the csv as floats instead of strings was to remove extraneous characters in the first place. I need the final output into the dictionary to contain nothing but the actual numbers from the csv, i.e. no quotes or brackets.

Below does return what I'm looking for, but there must be a more pythonic way to do this:

```
for row in cdata:    
    cdict[row[0]] = row.pop()
```

Example csv data:

```
Number;Value
0;13.168159
1;13.1681598889
2;13.0313661591
```

Comment: How many columns does the csv have? are all of them numbers?

Comment: Yes. Two columns, all numbers except for column headers. Headers are specified for both columns on first line of csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are only two columns I think this is more pythonic

```
cdata = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
print dict(cdata)
```